# Should I cut Hydrangea surfacing roots?

Tags: shrubs, hydrangea

My hydrangeas have sprouted roots above ground.  The shrubs are three years in.

> Can these roots be cut off without loosing the plant?

Comment: Could you illustrate your question with a picture?

Comment: Hydrangeas don't produce roots above ground - please post a photo showing the area

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, these might also be new branches growing! Can't tell without an image.

If your hydrangea grows roots above ground, another solution would be to add some compost or potting soil to the plants' feet.